# Object.keys() array with one element treated as string?

Tags: javascript, object

What kind of magic is that, when you Object.keys() on an object with one key only, it will be treated as a string when you reference later using square brackets?

See below for example:

```
let chosenProducts = [
  {
    toys: 20
  }  
];

let toys = "toys";

chosenProducts.forEach(product => {
  let name = Object.keys(product);

  console.log(Array.isArray(name)); // true
  console.log(name) // ['toys']
  console.log(toys) // "toys" - string
  console.log(product[name]); // 20 - array used = wtf?
  console.log(product[toys]); // 20 - string used

});
```

Comment: It's nothing magic about the array having only one element in it. Exactly the same thing happens if it has two or even more: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/L9vp7rhn/ It's just less likely to match a property in the object. (I've made it do so, by slipping non-enumerable properties into the object so their names don't appear in the array from `Object.keys`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array.

All objects have a `toString` method.

If you use an object in string context, `toString` is called implicitly.

Square-bracket property accessor notation is, essentially, string context (unless you pass a Symbol)

The default `toString` method on an array looks something like: `function () { return this.join(","); }`

```js
const example1 = ["foo", "bar"];
console.log("" + example1);

const example2 = ["baz"];
console.log("" + example2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys returns an array of keys. Your `name` variable is an array with one element `['toys']`. When you access `product[name]` implicit coercion of name array to string happens which results in `product["toys"]`

In javascript there are two types of coercions ***[implicit and explicit coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/types-grammar/ch4.md)***

When you access with Object's properties they will be string, in case of an array they will be indexes (numbers), but array is also an object, when you add any property in array it can be act as object property(string) and will not get counted towards the length of array.

```
let arr = [1,3];
arr.val = 20;
console.log(arr.length); // 2
```

In your example you are accessing object's property `product[name]` here `name` is an array. What will happen here is **implicit coercion of array to string**.
Javascript will automatically call `toString` method on your object which is an array in this case. There is `toString` method for `Array` which is linked to their prototype **Array.prototype.toString**. You can override that if you want to get different result.

In simple terms when you try to access variable in `if` conditional expression javascript automatically coerce to `Boolean` value.

```
let a = 10;
if(a){
    console.log("implicit coercion");
}

if(Boolean(a)){
    console.log("explicit coercion");
}
```

[To learn more about Javascript grammar and types.](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/types-grammar/README.md)